# Launch Java program on file using Windows "Open With" option

Tags: java, file

I want to make a Java program that can be executed on a file using the Windows "Open With..." menu option to read files and do things with them.  How do I accomplish this?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I highly encouraged to have look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and rephrase your question if possible so that your question get save from being downvoted also you can get solution of your problem

Comment: I am using windows 8.1

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-any-application-to-the-desktop-right-click-menu-in-vista/ - This can be done in windows 8 through the command line (using the reg binary shipped with windows). You can add the java -jar arguments where required.

Comment: what kind of file you want to run with java program?

Comment: I want to run it with a text file

Answer (score 2):

"Open with..." effectively executes the program with a string containing the absolute file path as the first parameter.  I.e. if I were to right click on "text.txt" in C:\Docs, and opt to open it with notepad, it would be exactly the same as typing the following in the windows command prompt:

```
notepad.exe "C:\Docs\text.txt"
```

Unfortunately, since java programs are executed via java, which itself requires additional parameters, and you lack the ability to control those parameters when using the Open With option, you are unable to use a java program to open a file directly.

Your best recourse is to use a wrapper script or program to open the jar for you with the file.  I use the following one-line Windows batch script as an example:

FancyTextProcessorLauncher.bat:

```
java -jar "user3838812sFancyTextProcessor.jar" %1
```

Place this script in the same directory as user3838812sFancyTextProcessor.jar (which represents your packaged program in this example).

Using Open With, select FancyTextProcessorLauncher.bat as the program to open the text file with.  This script launches Java with the appropriate parameters to run the jar containing your program, and feeds %1 (in Batch scripting land, the first parameter passed via command line) to your program as the first parameter.  You can then create a File object (or whatever is appropriate for what you intend to do) from the path that was passed in (accessible from your Main method as args[0]).